# Trying to get CSS hosted on Google Sites to work on eBay listing

Tags: html, css

I've been tasked with adding CSS to my company's eBay listings, but I'm struggling to get it to load. I've done some searching around and tried a few different things but nothing seems to work. I'm currently using Google Sites to host the CSS file, I'm not sure if this is the issue or not. I'm quite new to this. I've only done quite basic level HTML coding previously.

The advertisement I've tested on is [here](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/283438578225).

CSS:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.tabs {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tabs label {
    order: 1;
    display: block;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    background:  #3CC0F8;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: background ease 0.2s;
}

.tabs .tab {
    order: 99;
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    padding: 1rem;
    background: #fff;
}

.tabs input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background: #fff;
}

.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label + .tab {
    display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 45em) {
    .tabs .tab,
    .tabs label {
        order: initial;
    }

    .tabs label {
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-top: 0.2rem;
    }
}

body {
    background: #fff;
    min-height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 10vh;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.5;
    max-width: 61rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 112%;
}
```

Comment: `The resource from “https://sites.google.com/site/ebaykwfm/sizes/alpinestars%20style.css?attredirects=0” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).` Why is your file served as `text/html`? Do you have control over this to set it to `text/css`?

Comment: Sorry, thought I'd added in type="text/css", just added it now

Comment: Don't see the change yet, probably it takes some time to propagate. You can check developer tools console on Ebay site to see if you are still getting the error later.

Comment: The only error seems to now be : SCRIPT5002: Invalid operand to 'instanceof': Function expected rx_lidar.js (70,77)

Comment: It seems to be ok on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j3so6zcu/

Comment: Might be realted to ebay - https://community.ebay.co.uk/t5/Archive-Seller-Central/using-css-in-listing-description/m-p/4126935